# iPhone app's storyboard does not display correctly on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I've spent a lot of time attempt to research this issue and haven't gotten any results unfortunately.

[edit: being more explicit with my question]
My question is:  why are the objects on my view controller not appearing when I run the iPad simulator?  The background color of the view controller is displayed.  The navigation tab bar appears as well.  But neither of the two objects on my view controller appear (which have constraints on them).
[/edit]

If I look at the info.plist I see that I have "Main Storyboard file base name" with a value of Main (which makes sense, as my one and only storyboard is main.storyboard).

When I run the app within the iPhone simulator, all is well.  When I changed the simulator to iPad, this is what happens:

- Launch Screen appears
- View Controller appears with the background color I have chosen in my storyboard scene.
- When in debug, I see that it's going through the code to load up my views as it does when running in the iPhone simulator.
- The Tab Bar controller's tab bar appears at the bottom of the view controller as expected.

Is this somehow related to the width and height I have selected?  I have it set to: wCompact hAny.  When I change it to wAny hRegular, the items I had placed in the scene (a UIView and a UITextField) "disappear."

Some background:
I originally created the app as Universal.  But what I want, at least for now because I'm still learning, is just an iPhone app that will also run on an iPad (with that 2x option).  I changed the Targeted Device Family to iPhone under both the Target and then later under Project.

I know one option is to just make an iPad layout, but I'd really like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

[edit:  one solution]
The resolution I took, although I feel it's not the one I wanted, was to change the size to one that iPad supports and then paste the two objects (UIView & UITextView) into the scene that was defined as wAny hRegular.  Then I hooked up those 2 objects to their outlets in the View Controller and I now have my app appearing in the iPad simulator.

Comment: You haven't actually described what's going wrong.

Comment: I have a UITextView and a UIView in my View Controller.  When I run the app in an iPad simulator (or on my iPad) neither the UITextView nor the UIView appear.  They appear when I run the iPhone simulator.

I was thinking it may be related to the h/w at the bottom of the screen because when I change it to wAny hRegular, as noted in my post, those 2 objects are no longer in my scene.

Comment: Being new to Objective-C and xCode, when xCode 6 came about (which I had as a tag, but is gone now), they introduced size classes, which I did reference in my question.  However, from playing around with them and from a little reading about them, their purpose wasn't the most clear to me.  However, I found a video tutorial that really does a great job of explaining.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cz9VnXAKUo